# Spring CLI swallows chars from command?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, spring-boot, io

Right after starting my Java CLI app sometimes I get the following behaviour from the spring CLI:

```
Welcome to Spring Shell. For assistance press or type "hint" then hit ENTER.
11:04:38.871 [Spring Shell] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultPromptProvider'
spring> abort
Command 'aort' not found (for assistance press TAB)
spring> 11:04:41.322 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultPromptProvider'
// I hit an enter here
spring> 
Command 'b' not found (for assistance press TAB)
11:06:13.106 [Spring Shell] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'defaultPromptProvider'
```

So it randomly keeps some chars from the CLI in the buffer. This only happens while I'm using IDEA, when I use the packed jar, it works as expected. I have added to the VM options:

`-Djline.terminal=org.springframework.shell.core.IdeTerminal`